# Restructuring/sorting data in panda for ANOVA

Tags: pandas, anova

I want to manipulate a data set in order to make it suitable for ANOVA testing. The current way the df is structured is like df1, with many data points, of several types and separated by contextual categories. As I understand it (which may be wrong), I need to change the structure of the df so that it more resembles df2. I'm sure it's something to do with melt and sort, but I'm not sure how to get all the way there. What's the way/is there a better way to do ANOVA testing on this kind of data?

The real df I'm using has hundreds of data points, and many more types and categories, so it has to be a solution that can be applied realistically to more than 6 values.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'length': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
               'width': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
               'type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
               'type2': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'x']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A(x) length': [*length values that are types A,X*],
               'B(x) length': [*length values that are types B,X*],
               'C(x) length': [*length values that are types C,X*]})
```

**edited df2 to more accurately reflect what I'm asking. Maybe df restructuring isn't the answer - How would I write the anova prompt to apply the test to df1?

```
fvalue, pvalue =f_oneway(df2[*Axlength*], df2[*Bxlength*], df2[*Cxlength*])
```

Comment: Can you give the logic as to how you got df2 from df1?

Comment: I just made df2 by hand, but the idea is that any given data point is either length or width, and can be separated by both type and type 2. So how would I restructure such that any given column is comprised only of the same kind of data point, ie col1 is length values that are type =A and type 2 =x. Col2 is length values that are type =B type2 = x. etc.?

Comment: because I just did it by hand, copy and pasting for the example, the numbers don't match up. Really, the first column of A(x) length would only have one value = 1 because there's only one value in df1 that is 'A(x) length'

Comment: `df.assign(id = df.groupby(['type', 'type2']).cumcount()).pivot('id', ['type', 'type2'])`

Comment: How would I refer to the columns in the ANOVA context: fvalue, pvalue =f_oneway(df2['A(x)'], df2['B(x)'], df2['C(x)'], df2['D(x)'])

Comment: its a multiindexed dataframe

Comment: Your `df2` is not valid, can you clarify which output you expect exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The exact expected output remains unclear, but you might want:

```
df2 = df.melt(['type', 'type2'])
group = df2['type']+'('+df2['type2']+') '+df2['variable']
df2 = df2.groupby(group)['value'].agg(list)
```

Output:

```
A(x) length       [1]
A(x) width        [1]
A(y) length       [4]
A(y) width        [4]
B(y) length    [2, 5]
B(y) width     [2, 5]
C(x) length    [3, 6]
C(x) width     [3, 6]
Name: value, dtype: object
```